# How to hide / protect WCF URL in JQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to interact with a WCF REST service. I would like to somehow hide or secure the url of my service..but I have no idea how to do this, any help?

```
function getMyUser() {
        var query = { "pLastName": null };
        query.pLastName = "m";
        var label = document.getElementById("idGetUsersByLastName");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "//THE URL I WANT TO HIDE",
                data: JSON.stringify(query),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {

                    var zx = 5652;
                    label.innerHTML = data;
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var zx = 5652;
                    MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
                        label.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
                    });
                }
            });
        });


    };
```

I believe something like going back to the server to check what the url is would work but no idea how to implement it.

Comment: You can't. I can just open the Chrome developer tools requests viewer and watch your AJAX requests.

Comment: Even if you could obfuscate that URL, a user could still use Firebug or the XHR Chrome console to see what URL is being requested.

Comment: short answer is you can't. long answer is you can not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide it, and knowing that, you should make sure that you do an appropriate level of  authentication you need to in order to prevent tampering/abuse - whether it be rate throttling or authentication.

You can't count on someone just not knowing about it as being good enough security - someone will eventually find it, and they will try to break it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to hide the URL, try to fortify your service script by adding checks for unauthorized activity.